# Is it possible to redirect output to a file using the redirection operator without writing a byte-order mark in Powershell?

Tags: file, powershell, byte-order-mark

Is there any way to omit the byte-order mark when redirecting the output stream to a file? For example, if I want to take the contents of an XML file and replace a string with a new value, I need to do create a new encoding and write the new output to a file like the following which is rather ham-handed:

```
$newContent = ( Get-Content .\settings.xml ) -replace 'expression', 'newvalue'
$UTF8NoBom = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding( $false )
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText( '.\settings.xml', $newContent, $UTF8NoBom )
```

I have also tried using `Out-File`, but specifying `UTF8` as the encoding still contains a BOM:

```
( Get-Content .\settings.xml ) -replace 'expression', 'newvalue' | Out-File -Encoding 'UTF8' .\settings.xml
```

What I want to be able to do is simply redirect to a file without a BOM:

```
( Get-Content .\settings.xml ) -replace 'expression, 'newvalue' > settings.xml
```

The problem is that the BOM which is added to the output file routinely cause issues when reading these files from other applications (most notably, most applications which read an XML blow up if I modify the XML and it begins with a BOM, Chef Client also doesn't like a BOM in a JSON attributes file). Short of me writing a function like `Write-FileWithoutBom` to accept pipeline input and an output path, is there any way I can simply "turn off" writing a BOM when redirecting output to a file?

The solution doesn't necessarily *have* to use the redirection operator. If there is a built-in cmdlet I can use to output to a file without a BOM, that would be acceptable as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- In ***Windows PowerShell* as of v5.1** (the latest and *last* version), there is **NO (direct) built-in way to get UTF-8 encoding *without a BOM***.

  - In v5.1+ you can change the default encoding for `>` / `>>` as follows, but if you choose `utf8`, you *still* get a BOM:

    - `$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'`
  - **To avoid a BOM**, either **direct use of .NET APIs** or a **workaround via `New-Item`** is required - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553739/45375).
  - Unfortunately, it is unlikely that *Windows PowerShell* will ever support creation of BOM-less UTF-8 files.<sup>[1]</sup>
- **PowerShell *Core* (v6+), by contrast, uses *BOM-less* UTF-8 *by default*** (both for `Out-File` / `>` and `Set-Content`) and offers you a choice of BOM or no-BOM via `-Encoding` specifiers `utf8` and `utf8BOM`.

---

<sup>[1] From a [Microsoft blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/07/14/powershell-6-0-roadmap-coreclr-backwards-compatibility-and-more/), emphasis added: "**Windows PowerShell 5.1**, much like .NET Framework 4.x, will continue to be a built-in, supported component of Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016. However, it **will likely not receive major feature updates or lower-priority bug fixes.**" and, in a comment, "The **goal with PowerShell Core 6.0** and all the compatibility shims is to **supplant the need for Windows PowerShell 6.0 while converging the ecosystem on PowerShell Core**. So no, we currently **don’t have any plans to do a Windows PowerShell 6.0.**"</sup>

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to hear, but I appreciate you taking the time to explain *how* the default encoding can be overridden. It's also good to know `Powershell Core` does support this, so it hopefully means `Microsoft Powershell 6.0` will also support it.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest: Unfortunately, it sounds like _Windows PowerShell_ (as opposed to PowerShell _Core_) will not gain any new features - please see my update.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say `Windows Powershell`, not `Microsoft`. Guess I'm late to the party, but at least Microsoft has committed to which flavor of Powershell they will be developing moving forward.

Comment: Where can I learn about this kind of encoding? I always see this kind of stuff and never know what it means.

Comment: @Abraham, you can start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding for an overview. The various Unicode encodings have dedicated pages, such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8