# accented french characters with powershell core 7.1.2 or 7.2 don't work

Tags: powershell

On powershell core (7.1.2) or 7.2, I don't have the accented  french characters "é" or "è" or "à", I have this:

Liste des mises Ã  jours dÃ©jÃ  installÃ©es dans la derniÃ¨re mise Ã  jour

It works on powershell windows 5.1. the text is like this:

Liste des mises à jours déjà installées dans la dernière mise à jour

I use the IDE visual studio code in the 2 cases.

Whats is the solution please?
I have already tried to change the encoding : utf8 or utf 16 for example with the french language pack

I tried this code for example, but it doesn't work

```
#affiche la tentative de mise à jour"
function affichetentative {
 
    #nom du serveur
    $b=HOSTNAME.EXE
    #chemin  où  est lecalisé le fichier de log du serveur
    $path="C:\LOGS\log_$b.txt"
    #affichage du texte ci-dessous dans un fichier de log
    $c=Get-Date
    $a="Liste des mises à jours déjà installées dans la dernière mise à jour le {0} " -f  $c
    ADD-content -path $path -Encoding utf8BOM -value  $a  
        
    }
 affichetentative
```

I have this output in my file:

Liste des mises Ã  jours dÃ©jÃ  installÃ©es dans la derniÃ¨re mise Ã  jour le 16/02/2021 22:13:41

even if i configure utf8BOM or UTF-16LE on visual studio code, it doesn't work

Comment: I'm ok on Windows 10 with that. Maybe this is your terminal\console\font problems? Try printing file with this text to console without powershell (using `type` or `cat`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implication is that your file is UTF8-encoded, but *without a BOM*.

- **Caveat**: If you use [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content) to *append* to an existing file (that isn't empty), PowerShell *matches the (possibly inferred) existing encoding* and *ignores an `-Encoding` argument*.

While PowerShell (Core) 7+ reads such files correctly, *Windows PowerShell* does not, because it assumes *ANSI* encoding in the absence of a BOM; this applies both to files read *explicitly* with `Get-Content` and *implicitly* read *source-code* files.

**Any file you want *both* PowerShell editions to interpret correctly *by default* should be UTF8-encoded *with a BOM*** (or UTF16-LE-encoded, which PowerShell calls `Unicode`, which *always* has a BOM).

The pitfall is that **modern editors such as Visual Studio Code create *BOM-less* files by default**, because UTF8 is assumed to be the *default* encoding nowadays, and because some utilities, notably those with a Unix heritage, do *not* expect a BOM and may even misinterpret as *data*.

- However, as [filimonic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1936966/filimonic) points out, you can ***configure* Visual Studio Code** to create UTF8 files *with* BOM by default (optionally just for PowerShell source-code files) - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/vscode/understanding-file-encoding#configuring-vs-code).

---

**From *Windows PowerShell***, the **problem can be demonstrated** as follows:

```
# Use a .NET API directly to create a test file.
# .NET APIs create BOM-*less* UTF-8 files by default.
[IO.File]::WriteAllText(
  "$PWD/test.txt",
  'Liste des mises à jours déjà installées dans la dernière mise à jour'
)

# Now read it with Get-Content on Windows PowerShell, which
# results in MISINTERPRETATION.
# Note: In PowerShell (Core) 7+, this works correctly.
Get-Content test.txt
```

You'll get:

```
Liste des mises Ã  jours dÃ©jÃ  installÃ©es dans la derniÃ¨re mise Ã  jour
```

because the UTF8 encoding was misinterpreted as the active ANSI code page's encoding.

By passing `-Encoding utf8` to `Get-Content`, you could avoid the problem.

Comment: It works for me with   the encoding  unicode or utf32. Thanks!  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Glad to hear it, @geekdu972. `Unicode` is PowerShell-speak for UTF16-LE, which definitely works (as does UTF32), but note that you'll get much larger files than with UTF8 (with BOM), if the file is primarily composed of ASCII-range characters.

Comment: @mklement0 When working with files you can use encoding `$utf8bom = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new($true)` which keeps BOM record
`[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($path, $lines, $utf8bom)`, `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($path, $text, $utf8bom)`

Comment: @filimonic, yes, but if you _do_ want a BOM in PowerShell code, just use `-Encoding utf8` in Windows PowerShell, and `-Encoding utf8bom` in PowerShell (Core) 7+; if you _don't_ want a BOM in Windows PowerShell, you indeed have to use .NET APIs - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51847431/45375) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34969243/45375) for a cmdlet-like wrapper function. (In PowerShell (Core) 7+ you'll get BOM-less UTF8 by default, consistently across all cmdlets).

Comment: Thank you! This is not intuative, I saved my scripts as `UTF-8-BOM` and my problem was solved